# Assigning dynamic bash variable names using a for loop seq

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So I'm trying to do something, not sure if it's possible. I have the following code:

```
for i in {0..5}; do
    if [[ -f ./user$i ]]; then
        group$i=$(grep -w "group" ./user0|awk '{print $2}'|perl -lape 's/\s+//sg')
```

What I want to do is assign a unique variable for each instance of the {0..5} so group1 group2 group3 group4 for each variable name. Then I would change ./user0 to ./user$i and create a dynamic list of variables based on my sequence.
Is this possible? I get the following error when trying to execute this and I'm unsure of what I have actually done that bash doesn't like.

> test.sh: line 16: group0=j: command not found

Comment: I recommend using bash arrays instead of dynamic variable names if possible.

Comment: @KurtStutsman -- I was thinking that as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kurt Stutsman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459615/kurt-stutsman) provides the right pointer in a comment on the question: **use Bash *arrays*** to solve your problem.

Here's a simplified example:

```
groups=() # declare an empty array; same as: declare -a groups
for i in {0..5}; do
  groups[i]="group $i"  # dynamically create element with index $i
done

# Print the resulting array's elements.
printf '%s\n' "${groups[@]}"
```

<sup>See the bottom of this answer for other ways to enumerate the elements of  array `${groups[@]}`.</sup>

- `bash` arrays can be dynamically expanded (and can even be *sparse* - element indices need not be contiguous)

  - Hence, simply assigning to element `$i` works, without prior sizing of the array.
- Note how `$i` need *not* be prefixed with `$` in the array subscript, because array subscripts are evaluated in an *arithmetic* context (the same context in which `$(( ... ))` expressions are evaluated).

---

As for **what you did wrong**:

```
group$i=...
```

is not recognized as a variable assignment by Bash, because - taken *literally* - `group$i` is not a valid identifier (variable name).

Because it isn't, Bash continues to parse until the next shell metacharacter is found, and then interprets the resulting word as a *command* to execute, which in your case resulted in error message `group0=j: command not found`.

---

If, for some reason, you don't want to use *arrays* to avoid this problem entirely, you can ***work around* the problem**:

By involving a variable-declaring *builtin* [command] such as `declare`, `local`, or `export`, you force Bash to perform expansions *first*, which expands `group$i` to a valid variable name before passing it to the builtin.

- [user2683246's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683246/user2683246) demonstrates the *next best* approach by using `declare` (or, if local variables inside a function are desired, `local`) to create the variables.
- [Soren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/668501/soren) uses `export`, but that is only advisable if you want to create *environment* variables *visible to child processes* rather than mere *shell* variables.

**Caveat**: With this technique, **be sure to *double-quote the RHS*** in order to capture the full value; to illustrate:

```
 i=0; declare v$i=$(echo 'hi, there'); echo "$v0" # !! WRONG -> 'hi,': only UP TO 1ST SPACE

 i=0; declare v$i="$(echo 'hi, there')"; echo "$v0" # OK -> 'hi, there'
```

---

Other ways to enumerate the `groups` array created above:

```
# Enumerate array elements directly.
for element in "${groups[@]}"; do
  echo "$element"
done

# Enumerate array elements by index.
for (( i = 0; i < ${#groups[@]}; i++ )); do
  echo "#$i: ${groups[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But I'm having trouble understanding how to assign the values to my other variables that I provided above. I understand how your example works but how do I apply that to my group=$(command) syntax?

Comment: Oh nvmnd. I got it working. I don't fully understand why this works though. group[i]="group$i"
group[i]=$(grep -w "group" ./user$i|awk '{print $2}'|perl -lape 's/\s+//sg')

Comment: So this does work, but what about the rest of my problem as edited above? How do I write each value to a file and have it be unique? My Echo statement does not work when attempting this with ${group[@]}. Obviously if I change it to [1] it will work but how do I do it for each variable dynamically?

Comment: Oh I think I just figured it out. It would be ${group[$i]}.

Comment: Yes, though as explained in the answer, `"${groups[i]}"` (no `$` sigil needed) will do - also, be sure to _double-quote_ variable references (whether arrays, array elements, or scalars), unless you want to subject them to word splitting and pathname expansion by the shell.

Answer (score 4):

Use `declare group$i=...` instead of just `group$i=...`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the export or declare function like this

```
for i in {0..5}; do
    if [[ -f ./user$i ]]; then
        export group$i=$(grep -w "group" ......
```

with declare

```
for i in {0..5}; do
    if [[ -f ./user$i ]]; then
        declare group$i=$(grep -w "group" ......
```

where `export` makes the value available to sub-processes, and `declare` just available within the same script.

Comment: Oh man. PERFECT. Worked 100%. Do you mind explaining to me WHY this worked? I am reading up on the export command but I don't fully understand why this works.

Comment: Updated my code above with another question for you. This works but I ran into another issue.

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than updating

Comment: Ah. Well I can do that. I was hoping for your insight. Haha.

Comment: There is no good reason to use `export`, unless you need to create _environment_ variables visible to _child_ processes.
In Bash, the right choice is to use _arrays_; the next best option is to use `declare` (or `local`), as 
demonstrated in [@user2683246's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35592368/45375).

Comment: Aside from that: unless you _double-quote_ the RHS, only its value _up to the first space_ will be captured, so it should be `export group$i="$(...)"`.

Comment: -1 re: unnecessary `export`, flat-inaccurate suggestion of `set` (`set foo=bar` changes `$1` to the string `foo=bar`. If this were suggesting `declare` instead, I'd be neutral on it.