# Bash loop to fetch different variables

Tags: string, bash, variables, unix

Is it possible to do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
noOfParameters=2
paramname1="test1"
paramname2="test2"
i=0
while [ $i -ne ${noOfParameters} ]
  do 
     i=`expr $i + 1`
     echo ${paramname$i}
 done
```

I am trying to achieve output as

```
test1
test2
```

I am getting `"main.sh: line 10: ${paramname$i}: bad substitution"` error

Comment: Better use an array

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of ["Assigning dynamic bash variable names using a for loop seq"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592272/assigning-dynamic-bash-variable-names-using-a-for-loop-seq) (solution: use an array). Also, use bash's builtin math, like `i=$((i + 1))` or just `((i++))`, instead of `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally do this using an array

```
arr[0]="test"
arr[1]="test2"

for item in "${arr[@]}"
do
  printf "%s\n" "$item"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indirect references like

```
for ((i=1;i<3;i++)); do
   varname=paramname$i
   echo "${!varname}"
done
```

Perhaps you can bypass your problems with something like

```
set | grep -E "paramname[12]=" | cut -d"=" -f2
```